# using jruby to manipulate algorithms in weka

Tags: for-loop, machine-learning, jruby, weka

how do I begin using jruby with weka, as am new to programming. aim is to manipulate machine learning algorithms in weka using jruby to achieve active learning.

for instance active learning with SVM's, How? and where to begin with?

Thanks a lot for your time and effort

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your best bet would be Scala.
[scala+IDEA+SBT](http://neglectorientedprogramming.tumblr.com/post/68855288107/sbt-intellij-idea-scala-debian-wheezy-how-to-best)

Answer (score 0):

Now there a Weka wrapper for JRuby: you can find it at  https://github.com/paulgoetze/weka-jruby.